# Can we provide URL instead asset In FlareActor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flare

Is it possible to give firebase Url instead of asset in flareActor in flutter?

Comment: You're not forced to used an asset, but there is no built-in method for giving it a URL.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherMoore for replying but is there any way or alternative way?

Comment: Yes you can use one of the alternative constructors.

Comment: which is? Could you please elaborate??  This link is the official doc and nothing useful given here, https://pub.dev/documentation/flare_flutter/latest/flare_actor/FlareActor-class.html

Comment: There are **4** constructors in the link you shared. Only 2 are related to assets. Use the other 2.

Comment: Hey, @ChristopherMoore none of them takes an URL.

Comment: As I said before, there is no built-in method of using a URL. Use one of the alternatives.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Comment: Hello @ChristopherMoore, thank you for answering, I will be testing it out within a week then I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see something that takes a URL that points to data as a parameter, it must being doing a network request at some point to obtain that data. Since there is no URL constructor for a `FlareActor`, do *your own* network request with the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http). Add the appropriate version to your pubspec.yaml dependencies.

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.2
```

Import the package into the file where you need the `FlareActor`. Do a `get` request to obtain the data and pass the data to the [`FlareActor.memory` constructor](https://pub.dev/documentation/flare_flutter/latest/flare_actor/FlareActor/FlareActor.memory.html).

```dart
var resp = await get(url);

FlareActor actor = FlareActor.memory(resp.bodyBytes);
```

Wrap the above code in a `Future` function and use a `FutureBuilder` in `build` to show your flare actor on the screen once it's ready.